# Program that converts numbers to letters both ways

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program that encodes and decodes letters to numbers. I have the Encoding properly built but the decoding is giving me problems. I'm using int to char conversions with the ASCII table as the key. It doesn't seem like the conversion logic for the decoding is right but I really have no idea how to fix it. This is my first time using this conversion method so I still don't fully understand it.

*edit This is on a windows form app that has three buttons and two text boxes. Encode is one button, and you type in a sentence and it outputs in in numbers for each letter. Decode is another but it does the opposite type in numbers and get words. the third button is clear so thats not important. Sorry I left this out of the initial question.

```
class LetterCodeLogic
{
    public static string Encode(string msg)
    {
        string result = "";
        string m = msg.ToUpper();
        char c;
        int x;
        for(int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
        {
            c = Convert.ToChar(m[i]);
            x = c;
            if (x == 32)
            {
                x = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                x -= 64;
                if (x < 1 || x > 26)
                {
                    x = 99;
                }
            }
            result += x.ToString() + " ";
        }

        return result;
    }
    public static string Decode(string msg)
    {
        string result = "";
        string[] nums = msg.Split(',');
        char c;
        int x;
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.Length; i++)
        {
            x = Convert.ToChar(msg[i]);
            c = (char)x;
            if (c == 0)
            {
                c = (char)32;
            }
            else
            {
                c -= (char)64;
                if (c < 65 || c > 90)
                {
                    c = (char)35;
                }
            }
            result += c.ToString() + " ";
        }

        return result;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: By the way, you can use character literals (like, for example `'A'` instead of numbers in your comparisons, then the reader doesn't have to guess what magic `64` holds. I'm curious what the point of this code is

Comment: It seems your Encode method creates a space-delimited string, but Decode attempts to parse a comma-delimited string.

Comment: Also, `Convert.ToChar` will use Unicode encoding by default, not ASCII.  If you really want to use ASCII, you may need to explore [`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.ascii?view=netcore-3.1).  Though I guess you may not care about the actual encoding used, as long as it's the same for both encoding and decoding.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to recreate existing functionality in c#. If you cast a `char` to an `int`, you can cast that `int` back to a `char`, without creating any if/else logic. The only thing you'll need to fix is your inconsistent delimiters (as @JohnWu mentioned)

Answer (score 4):

I find problems like this are far easier when you break them into parts. First, write functions that convert a single character to a number or vice versa.

```
static public byte Encode(char c)
{
    if (c == ' ') return 0;
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') return (byte)(c - 'A' + 1);
    return 99;
}

static public char Decode(byte n)
{
    if (n == 0) return ' ';
    if (n >= 1 && n <= 27) return (char)(n + 'A' - 1);
    return '#';
}
```

Now the functions you need are very easy to write:

```
static public string Encode(string stringInput)
{
    return string.Join(" ", stringInput.Select(Encode).Select( b => b.ToString() ));
}

static public string Decode(string numericInput)
{
    return new string(numericInput.Split(' ').Select( n => byte.Parse(n)).Select(Decode).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Im sorry i guess i wasnt clear in the question, and i will edit the inital question to reflect what i need better. This is on a windows form app that has three buttons and two text boxes. Encode is one button, and you type in a sentence and it outputs in in numbers for each letter. Decode is another but it does the opposite type in numbers and get words. the third button is clear so thats not important. Id be nice id it could be refined down to what you have though.

Comment: Those requirements are consistent with the code I provided.